# Find and modify all cells in a database that contain a keyword

Tags: php, mysql

I want to write a MySQL query that updates *all* cells in an entire database that contain a certain word, with a certain word. E.g:

```
UPDATE (any cell, any table) SET (the cells) = '$foo' WHERE (the cell) CONTAINS '$bar')
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Try [`REPLACE()`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-replace.aspx)

Comment: There is no quickfire solution to this: You'll need to do it on a table by table/column by column basis.

Comment: Mark, would it be possible for me to write PHP to generate the queries to automate this?

Comment: Yes, you need to create a script for this. Select all the rows, skip the primare key, loop through columns, and check them, and build a query, what columns should be updated. Do not use mysql functions, mysqli functions are deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instad. And escape your variables, because of sql injection attacks.